# Determining User Location - iOS

Tags: ios, mkannotation, location-services, mklocalsearchrequest

I am able to set annotations within some specified KM radius of the user current location (lets say for annotations are indicating pizza search points). But if the user drags the map left/right/top/bottom then is there any way to refresh the map and add annotations for new pizza locations in the new visible area of the map? Please suggest.

Comment: You should use [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html). It has methods that signals a change visible area 
**mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:** and **mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:**

Answer (score 0):

Try with using following `Method`

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"Pin dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```